# Can I isolate a onewire device using a bidirectional serial isolator?

Tags: digital-logic, isolation, onewire

I'm designing a board which has five onewire channels. One non-isolated, four isolated (spanning one isolation barrier rather than four separate barriers).

Can I simply run the onewire bus through a bidirectional serial isolator like an ISO1541, assuming it has pull-ups both sides? This would theoretically give me one device per isolation channel.

While I could use a DS2428-800 on the isolated side of the barrier, I'd prefer not to due to software complexity - each onewire bus has a single unique ID chip attached, and rather than implement all the required DS2428 features I'd rather just bit bang the unique ID devices once at device startup using the arduino onewire library.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the complete lack of responses I ordered some parts and built my own test circuit; using a TMA1205S isolated DC-DC converter, an ISO1541 and a DS2401. I connected the onewire bus to the SDA pins of the ISO1541, gave each side the requisite 5K1 pull up, and it appears to work fine.

So the answer is yes, you can use a bidirectional i2c isolator for onewire isolation. This works out well for both my BOM cost and development time.